# Track events iOS app's

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Can I track events in other app?

What I mean: I have an app that have to tracks all event on current device.

For example:
- Read iBooks
- Send SMS
- View youtube video
- and other

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in an App Store app. This would obviously be a huge invasion of the user's privacy.

You could write a jailbreak tweak that does this, however.